# Using an array to updated a stored array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I have an array of stored products.

```
[
  {
    sku: "RED",
    _id: "123"
  },
  {
    sku: "BLUE",
    _id: "abc"
  }
]
```

I also have this array duplicated on the front end which allows a user to edit. When the user edits this array will determine whether the objects within the saved array are deleted or added. The easiest solution would be to replace the saved array with the frontend array, however, the saved array also contains other data that I don't want to lose unless it's been directly edited.

So for example, if I was the remove `{ sku: "BLUE", _id: "abc" }` from the front end array, I would like to loop through the 'saved' array and remove the object which contains the blue sky object.

If the user was to create a new object such as a Green sku object:

```
[
  {
    sku: "RED",
    _id: "123"
  },
  {
    sku: "BLUE",
    _id: "abc"
  },
  {
    sku: "GREEN",
    _id: "jhg"
  }
]
```

The Green Sku object would be applied to the already saved array.

Since the saved array is stored on a DB, I would have to use javascript promises (await deleteProduct(_id) or await createProduct(_id))

What is the best way to achieve this using es6 javascript.

Comment: Maybe you could use [JS Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0):

Semi completed - sorry but might help?

Take both arrays say -

```
let frontEnd = [
  {
    sku: "RED",
    _id: "123"
  },
  {
    sku: "BLUE",
    _id: "abc"
  }
]

let backEnd = [
  {
    sku: "RED",
    _id: "123"
  },
  {
    sku: "BLUE",
    _id: "abc"
  },
  {
    sku: "GREEN",
    _id: "jhg"
  }
]
```

Then use the spead oportator to combine the two - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
let combined = [...frontEnd, ...backEnd]
```

then iterate over that array to remove any duplications that you might have found, then save the combined version?